# C# binding to multiple controls - > selection changes at every control

Tags: c#, binding, controls

I have a problem with binding to multiple controls. For example I have different controls: 1 listbox, 2 comboboxes, 1 datagridview and all of them have a binding to the same list or iobservablecollection (and except the datagridview display the same property). Everything works fine. But, if I change the selection of one control, the selection of all the other controls change to the same item. Or in other words, if I change the selection of a combobox to item Number 5, the other combobox changes it's selection to Number 5 as well and the listbox changes it's selection also to item Number 5. Does anybody know how to avoid this?

edit:
Here's  sample code that leads to the same behavior:

private List TestList;

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestList = new List<foo>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            foo f = new foo();
            f.test = "Test_" + i;
            TestList.Add(f);
        }
        comboBox1.DataSource = TestList;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "test";
        comboBox2.DataSource = TestList;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "test";
    }

    class foo
    {
        private string _test;
        public string test
        {
            get
            {
                return _test;
            }
            set
            {
                _test = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I change the ite of combobox1 the item of combobox2 changes automatically to the same item.

picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSr8U.png)

Comment: Maybe you can put the code that have problem to be much easier to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your controls but your datasources for both
 comboBox1.DataSource = TestList; and   comboBox2.DataSource = TestList; are the same. So when you change something in one its going to affect the other.

Comment: Yes, the source is the same and when you change data in the datasource, it affects both controls, of course. But that the datasource seems to have a property "selected value/item" makes no sense to me....

Answer (score 0):

I found at least a temporary solution that does not show this behavior.

from:

```
combobox1.DataSource = TestList;
```

to:

```
combobox1.DataSource = Testlist.ToList();
```

For all who have the same problem, please have a look at these links:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2007/09/19/binding-multiple-combo-boxes-to-the-same-data-source/

and

[One DataSource for multiple controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713218/one-datasource-for-multiple-controls)